# Oceanbase tag is being used for fake questions and answers

Tags: discussion, spam

I noticed that all questions under the [oceanbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oceanbase) tag and almost all answers are probably fake:

- Almost all are [extremely vague and short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72402155/how-different-is-cloud-from-oceanbase-enterprise), except for a couple that seem to contain [just a bit of script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72390015/oceanbase-ce-3-1-0-cannot-flashback-delete-table/72527085#72527085), but still make no sense
- All were posted in May 2022, in fact most were posted in May 27-30.
- Almost all of the answers are low-quality generic answers linking to the vendor's documentation landing page.
- The linked pages are in Chinese and don't even seem to be relevant to the questions.
- Others are feature lists
- All asker and answerer accounts were created on the same day the questions were asked.

And the funniest thing, one of the "accounts" goes from [asking about Paxos usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72344136/what-is-the-advantage-of-oceanbase-using-paxos-algorithm-over-other-distributed) one day to [not knowing what partitioning is for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72422658/what-role-does-partitioning-play-in-oceanbase) 6 days later.

Comment: Tag's gone now.  (Mostly) wasn't me, so I can't take the credit.  In the future, custom flags are probably better than a meta post, as you really need moderators to solve this.  There's not a lot the Meta community can do here.

Comment: I've tagged or reported all 40 `oceanbase` questions and answers already. Started from a fishy answer but quickly realized there was a pattern

Comment: The flags were good and definitely the right approach (I didn't acknowledge them in my original comment to maintain confidentiality of your flags unless you chose to mention them).

Comment: Is OceanBase itself legitimate? [From CGTN's website](https://web.archive.org/web/20211105010154/https://news.cgtn.com/news/2019-10-06/Ant-Financial-s-OceanBase-outstrips-Oracle-breaks-world-record--KzPIFpDgNG/index.html): *"Ant Financial, a subsidiary of Chinese giant Alibaba, has outstripped veteran player Oracle's rival product with its self-developed database called OceanBase to become the world's No.1 in terms of performance"*. [CGTN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China_Global_Television_Network)'s web site: *"China Global Television Network (CGTN) is the international division of..."* -

Comment: cont' - *"state media outlet China Central Television (CCTV)"*. The reference is from [a non-English Wikipedia page](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/OceanBase).

Comment: Should I add a `fraud-detection` tag to the question? In fact, identifying such accounts and transactions is probably one of the easi(er) fraud detection algorithms. It's weird talking about fraud in a Q&A site though

Comment: *"It's weird talking about fraud in a Q&A site though"* Oh how I wish fraud were rare here...whether it's spam, plagiarism, or voting fraud, there's no shortage of it.  But we remove it whenever we catch it, and we catch it pretty often, so we'll take it as a compliment that it largely goes unnoticed :-)

Comment: Oh, I do notice, eg around exam time or end of semester. I've also noticed upvoting rings in the past (but not recently). And I suspect I've seen high-rep accounts with naïve questions in their area of "expertise" that make me suspect the account was sold.

Comment: I never really understand what people think they gain from buying a [so] account; to try impress a potential employer? Surely a *good* employer would notice the person can't do the things their account says they can when they interview them, or (worse) when they employ them and can't complete the work they've been assigned which their [so] account implies they knew how to do easily.

Comment: @Larnu not all employers are good. And sometimes, especially for outsourcing agencies, the aim is to find enough bodies for the actual employer.

Comment: That's why I added emphasis to *good*, @PanagiotisKanavos .

Comment: @RyanM-Regenerateresponse You'll need to remove your pretty `status-completed` tag now.

Comment: It does look suspicious. The last six questions with an average span of about 7 minutes (by six different users). And of the 89 visible questions, 53 questions were asked in the last 20 hours.

Comment: I found [one remaining question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67848375) with the tag, that pre-dated this Meta post. I removed it, since the fact that OP was apparently attempting to build from the Oceanbase repository, appears completely unrelated to the actual task or expertise needed to answer.

Answer (score 28):

I'm afraid this is no longer [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed): [***they’re baaaack***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oceanbase), with something like 89 (and endlessly rising) new spam questions as of this writing.

The community can and should spam-flag these into oblivion because it's all part of a deceptively undisclosed [*astroturfing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroturfing) campaign, which is forbidden on the SE network. It's part of a stealth marketing campaign by a hidden sponsor to hype their product by pretending to be legit users of the sponsor's product. These are not real users nor real questions. This is a [Code of Conduct violation against Inauthentic Usage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct/inauthentic-usage) which applies to every site on the SE network.

The previous incarnation of these spammers 15 months ago was entirely extirpated by moderators; here's [one such example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72402155). They've recently noticed that Stack Overflow has lost its aegis of protection so they've returned to their wicked ways. If you check the timings of this new volley from them, they all fall within a narrow time-of-day window as well: it looks like it's an automated attack.

Notice what a Google search turns up [here on MSO](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com+oceanbase) and also [on SO main](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+oceanbase+-site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Sorry, we are on strike ;)

Comment: So we should spam flag *all* the questions? Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76592735/22152755) is spam too?

Comment: @LightningMcQueen Yes, because it's [astroturfing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroturfing), which is [***forbidden on the SE network***](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8323/astroturfing-on-stack-overflow) It's part of a stealth campaign by a hidden sponsor to hype their product. These are not real users nor real questions. The previous incarnation of these spammers 15 months ago [was entirely extirpated by moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72402155). They've recently noticed that SO has lost its aegis of protection so they've returned to their wicked ways.

Comment: @LightningMcQueen Look at the whole tag. Whatever is going on, it is definitely not legitimate, natural question asking-activity. Somebody is spewing in questions artificially, on the last couple days on the month.

Comment: For what it's worth, they didn't just start this after the moderation strike went info effect. From the questions that still show up on the tag page, they've been ramping it up since the end of March 2023.

Comment: Awesome. So let SE staff handle their own product. (**as if they'll do it.**)

Comment: Is there good reason to point out to them that it's happening, and how we're currently not going to do anything about it?

Comment: ... except it looks like someone (not me) did do something about it.

Comment: Seems the new bogus questions were deleted.

Comment: Why should it bother us? What's the problem it's against Code of Conduct? It's not our Code of Conduct.