# "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" when trying to access suspended users' meta profiles

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

I noticed that when I try to access [this user's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/531954/) [MSO profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/531954/), I get an *"Oops! Something Bad Happened! [...] It’s not you, it’s us. **This is our fault.**"*:

[image: Image showing the header "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" and that it's an error on Stack Exchanges side.]

Every other profile works fine for me.

Not sure if this is relevant, but that user is suspended network-wide. Also it's not like the meta user is destroyed completely, because [their comments on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418569/oceanbase-tag-is-being-used-for-fake-questions-and-answers#comment964524_425403) still contain a link to their profile. That is, it's not anonymized.

Comment: Had this happen for a suspended user earlier today (well; yesterday now). They had meta posts on several sites; tried clicking to their site specific meta profile from several of the posts, meaning, several different sites. Eventually searched with DDG, and found a few instances where it worked.

Comment: Can also confirm it happening on another suspended user's account.

Comment: If they are suspended I would say it shows the right message: Something Bad Happened. The only thing that needs fixing is "This is our fault". It is not.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this with both other (child) meta sites and other network suspended users.

Comment: @rene - I don't know ... but maybe from our perspective the message should read "something good happened" :-)

Comment: That image made me think your browser somehow popped a Windows 7 Basic Theme error message box.

Comment: Yep. [Another example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/549372/martin-zeitler).

Comment: (seems to work now)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was fixed on Aug 17.

It was caused by a fix to [another bug about translating suspension reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329117/164394).

When a user is suspended, the suspension is copied over to the meta site's profile, but it turns out the suspension `$reason$` (e.g. "network-wide", "for rule violations", etc) is *not* copied over.

So, for those user profiles, on meta sites only, the new translation code was hitting a null reference error.