# Apache AGE (of Despair)

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, duplicate-answers, clean-up

At the suggestion of a Mod in chat, I'm putting out a call for help in flagging the chaos in the [apache-age](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-age) answers which I (and several others) have noticed.

I'm not an expert in this area, but even I can see the obvious, multiple, very-low-quality and duplicate answers being posted on many of the questions in that tag.  It's a bit of an odd look for Stack Overflow, honestly.  We're (usually) much more curated than this.

I've done *some* flagging in this area, but:

1. It's a time-consuming slog, and I could use some help
2. Someone with more expertise here will be able to cull more answers than I can, especially when comparing SQL queries that may essentially be duplicates of each other.
3. Spreading the work out will (hopefully) keep any one person from going insane ;-)
4. If we can get this cleaned up quickly, I can get back to focusing on flagging AI answers (1,450+ flags and counting).

Some additional notes if you are willing to help:

- As the Mod who responded to my other flags reminded me, also use downvotes as appropriate when flagging.  If we get a number of downvotes on each answer, that can also be a sign that it's already been handled/flagged and doesn't need our attention.
- Don't get overly zealous (of course) - As always, if a post legitimately seems to improve upon existing answers, it likely has value.  And, of course, the first post with the info should *probably* get priority if it's of reasonable quality.

  I only say this because it can be too easy to get carried away when handling literally dozens (or hundreds) of these.
- Many of the questions, as well, appear off-topic and should be VTC'd.  IMHO, installing or configuring a database extension isn't a "programming" topic.
- Special thanks to @GeneralGrievance and @AndrewT in the comments for discovering that there may be an undisclosed affiliation in many of them.  [BOLO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=Newest&pagesize=50&q=%5bapache-age%5d%20url%3adev.to&searchOn=3) for these and flag appropriately.
- Keep an eye out for AI-generated answers as well.  While the major problem here is just VLQ's/duplicates, some are AI-generated.  Follow the user-profile to see if they have a history of AI answers and flag those appropriately as well if you would.  Honestly - This is part of the reason it's such a slog for me, as I often get pulled on a half-dozen rabbit trails in each of these questions.

Also, for any Mod reading this, in addition to curation of the content itself, it seems to me that some users could use warnings on the VLQ nature of their posts

Some examples:

- [Install and run apache/age and postgreSQL via docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76346877/11810933): At least 5 answers that say, *"use `age` instead of `age-server`
- [What would be the best result type for dates in AGE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76894826/11810933):  11 answers in two weeks, mostly saying (to quote one of them *"You can modify the return of the function for the `::date` cast operator of PostgreSQL. Or just use the `TO_DATE()` function for convert a string to a date."*

  Note that this was also *self-answered* with (it appears to me) the same info, before most of the posts needlessly repeated it.
- [Retrieving the graph's adjacency matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76900887/11810933):  10 answers, all of which essentially say, "No"
- [Apache age extension setting error while installation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76716399/11810933): 19 answers, most of which boil down to *"it's not installed correctly; reinstall"*
- [Permission issue for AGE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76859829/11810933): 17 answers, mostly variations on `sudo chown -R <user> /usr/local/pgsql/`.  A few "reinstall" answers.  IIRC, this is one where a user recommended `sudo make ...` and then 2 days later turned around and and said *"Don't use `sudo`*" for the same thing (it's likely those were AI).
- [Installing age-installation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76742635/11810933): 19 answers in 6 weeks, most *"Wrong version, use PG11*"

And many more ...

Comment: "*At least 5 answers that say, *"use age instead of age-server*" there is 7 answers total. That means 71% are just the same.

Comment: «10 answers, all of which essentially say, "No"». This is weird.

Comment: @AndreasismovingtoCodidact Yes, the whole situation is weird.  I just don't understand what is driving these duplicate/VLQ answers in this particular tag.

Comment: I (who is monitoring the [postgresql] tag) too noticed an influx of low-quality questions and answers related to [apache-age], to the point where I stopped ignoring them (mostly because I don't know the project and am not interested in it). Did they pull some popularity stunt that caused [this sudden increase](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1778932/apache-age-tag-trend-count-per-month#graph) over the last months? Is it limited to a certain region of the world?

Comment: My personal experience is with the question [Does the Apache Age database support multiple versions of the PostgreSQL protocol, including the extended query protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75716011/1048572), which got 9 answers but has barely 140 views. Why is this simple question (which is not motivated by a particular use case) so popular? I don't get it.

Comment: @Bergi No clue; wish I knew.  To add to the confusion, Apache took over AGE in May of 2022, but no SO questions appear in that tag until this year.  It seems that even the *questions* are often duplicates and VLQ as well.  It would be odd for any *organization* to be behind it, as Apache is (obviously) quite reputable.  It also appears to *tarnish* the "brand" more than anything.

Comment: For someone who wants to move to graph databases and is looking at evaluating AGE, this is a bit concerning.  Wouldn't know where to even begin, though.

Comment: Hm... a lot of same users doing this. Might be good to check for voting-rings/sockpuppet accounts too.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance One of my first thoughts, and I did identify one voting ring out of it a while back.  However, most of the answers aren't even upvoted!

Comment: @Makoto *"Wouldn't know where to even begin, though"* - If you don't have the expertise to dig in on the database queries themselves (and I don't either), then at least consider reviewing questions that probably aren't programming related and that you can vote-to-close.  Many of these are purely *database* driven, and should be on dba.stackexchange.com (and yet there are almost no AGE questions, nor even a tag, there) - That said, I wouldn't wish this plague on them either :-).  But at least let's close the ones that don't belong here, so they stop getting new VLQ answers.

Comment: The general weirdness around Apache AGE isn't new music. I've done cleanup rounds more than once, but apparently the deluge never stops. Glad that this is now a publicly known issue.

Comment: On what conditions should we flag posts with dev.to links? I feel like this could get messy without a mod involved.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance When they qualify as spam or link-only posts, I would think. Same as any other links in posts.

Comment: @TylerH What about the authors that are interns but link to other employees' posts? Would that be a custom flag for non-overt affiliation?

Comment: @GeneralGrievance no, a normal spam flag is just fine. The person's position at a company is irrelevant; if they are affiliated with a website they link to and don't disclose that, it's spam.

Comment: Is this the work of a bot maybe?

Comment: Possibly related ([astroturfing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroturfing)): *[The OceanBase tag is being used for fake questions and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418569/)* (recent, 2023-07 ([the return](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418569/oceanbase-tag-is-being-used-for-fake-questions-and-answers/425403#425403))) and *[What can we do about a tag that appears to be nothing more than astroturfing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358275/)*.

Comment: @QBrute I don't think so. More likely DavidW's [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426241/apache-age-of-despair#comment970855_426251) would explain it. That or a bot is doing a convincing job imitating this behavior.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance Right - That would be one scary bot if it had that many dev.to sock puppets writing articles and SO answers :-)

Comment: Could a charitable explanation be that they're attempting to teach new developers how to use stackoverflow?  e.g., like the [software carpentry](https://software-carpentry.org/) course on git encourages users to [collaborate via github](https://swcarpentry.github.io/git-novice/08-collab.html).  Doing this with public questions/answers feels disingenuous, but pointing to articles often happens in legitimate posts and they might just be copying that.  Still agree they should be cleaned up!

Comment: @Sam Mason: The [approximately same number of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76774948/error-in-the-following-code-and-not-able-to-solve-it#comment135783418_76774948) (on the order of 12) is suspicious. If the answers were voluntarily submitted, the expected distribution of number of answers would be expected to be much different (e.g., a [power law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law)). At least there is some kind of organisation/coordination going on. There may be an overlap in who answers (I haven't checked).

Comment: @PeterMortensen yup, something coordinated, but seems consistent with a training course where the instructors are encouraging students to write/find questions and answer them as well.  Agreed that the distribution is not consistent with normal usage, and answers themselves aren't providing much value.  But if it's really the first time a lot of them are using the service that would be consistent with a course.

Comment: @Sam Mason: It must be a long course then (or repeats). In [50 questions from April 2023](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-age?tab=newest&page=5&pagesize=50), 12 have 7 answers or more. ***All*** 50 questions have at least one answer. [Some tags with a similar number of (visible) questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=270&tab=popular). [One has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-batch) 10 questions without answers (still much better the average). And none with more than two answers (most have just one answer); this is close to the expected distribution.

Comment: Though it doesn't look like a voting ring (unless they are more sophisticated and wait several months until the attention is much lower (unlikely)).

Comment: @PeterMortensen just pulled out [questions and answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1779725/apache-age-qns-ans-users) and think I've invalidated my hypothesis.  I don't see any clustering by date (of the question or answer) nor does there seem to be any obvious groups of users in a graph where edges are drawn between question and answer `OwnerUserId`s

Comment: [Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76894826). Some have [now been culled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76179839/). There is [some overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21603421/nnaemeka-daniel-john) [between answerers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21559437/peter) for the two, more than three months apart (I am not implying anything).

Comment: Related: *[Extraordinary burnination: turn off the \[tdengine\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429255/extraordinary-burnination-turn-off-the-tdengine)*

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks!  I've seen (and flagged) a couple of other astroturfing tags, but not to that degree. :-/

Answer (score 46):

Strange pattern indeed. As some of us have noted, there's a lot of repeat users answering these questions. At first, I thought that there could have been voting fraud. However, NotTheDr01ds pointed out that a lot of these posts don't ever get upvoted, so it's unlikely to be the full story, though there does seem to be some involved.

Still, I thought this was weird, so I decided to Google two of them together, and I found that they are active contributors on [dev.to under the #postgres tag](https://dev.to/t/postgres). With the two I searched, they both turned out to be interns at Bitnine, [the original owners of Apache AGE](https://age.apache.org/overview/). Visiting a few more profiles, I saw several other employees or interns.

Andrew T. then noticed in a comment that [there were several posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=Newest&pagesize=50&q=%5bapache-age%5d%20url%3adev.to&searchOn=3) ([Updated after some cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=Newest&pagesize=50&q=%5bapache-age%5d%20url%3adev.to&searchOn=3)) under the tag that linked to dev.to articles and stated that they may be spamming/astroturfing here on SO. In response, I started looking at each of these answers and their authors. I tried to visit one post from every unique author of an answer.

Findings:

- Total posts visited: 24
- Confirmed Interns/Employees at Bitnine: 19. 18 interns, 1 associate developer.
- Profiles indicate recent/pending graduation, or internship of some kind: 22

Notes:

- Most, but not all of these linked to dev.to posts that were written by the author of the SO answers, and that I sometimes had to search dev.to directly to find the matching authors.
- It is also just a slice of the posts written by these users. Not everything they post here has a link.
- I think it's unlikely that these actions are motivated purely by self-promotion of their articles or SO reputation, but astroturfing for Bitnine/Apache AGE sounds very plausible.
- I don't have actual stats on this, but several users posting these repeat answers even *without* links also have accounts indicating internships at Bitnine.

Comment: My view is that this is probably mostly exploitative by Bitnine - they've clearly decided to outsource their development mainly to a bunch of interns who are mainly motivated by the possibility of getting a job (although I doubt any or many jobs are really on offer). It's all fairly odd, but to me it feels really sketchy by Bitnine and I just feel a bit sorry for the interns. It doesn't change the fact that a lot of the content doesn't belong on Stack Overflow of course.

Comment: I expect this is similar to the astroturfing that goes on with [tag:apache-iotdb]. Every few months I go on a flagging/downvote spree but it's impossible to keep up with it all.

Comment: Also, one of them has even put the tag on [a totally unrelated question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76774948/) and is hashtagging every single answer posted.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance Maybe they're just (ab)using StackOverflow's [apache-age] as a forum for their interns? Someone should reach out to them and recommend getting a private Team for that…

Comment: [It](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76774948/error-in-npm-i-command-running-to-install-node-modules) was viewed 158 times (till date) and got 12 answers. Isn't that an unusual conversion rate?

Comment: @PeterMortensen If you mean the ratio, then yes, for sure. A lot of other questions with this tag have similar characteristics.

Comment: Slight rabbit hole/update: Of the 20 top-answerers of all time, I found evidence that 15 of them have some kind of affiliation with Bitnine (some are a little sneaky about it), mostly through LinkedIn or Dev.to. I don't think there's nothing wrong with working for a company and posting here, but of course our posting guidelines do still apply.

Answer (score 15):

[Here's a SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1778922/2160762/apache-age-questions-sorted-by-answer-count) that shows the [apache-age](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-age) questions sorted by number of answers if you'd like to tackle the potential low-hanging fruit first.

On the downside, it will (hopefully) quickly become out-of-date as duplicates are culled.

Comment: Was just having a look at some of the answers and they're basically comments. There is one user who has *71* undeleted answers, 67 in that tag, and only *10* have a score > 0. 10 also have a score < 0 (so they have 51 zero score answers). *Blargh*.

Comment: @ThomA Yup - *Blargh*, along with "Despair" and "chaos", are really the *nicest* things we can say about it :-)