# Extraordinary burnination: turn off the [tdengine]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, moderation, spam-seeds

The [tdengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tdengine) tag has been plagued for at least since one year (possibly more) by what look like a massive seeding attempt via automatically created accounts, or plain ban evasion, at best, but again in massive numbers.

Moderators and community managers have been deleting and destroying these accounts in droves, however it just never stops.

Our theory is that someone set up a bot to repost questions about TDEngine products (non-spammy link: `https://www.taosdata.com/`, in Chinese) from their support WeChat group. I could not join the group to ascertain this because it's gated behind some AI assistant that asks me which product I use, and I don't feel like lying — however the available evidence points in this direction.

IIRC, there is no evidence that the socks are voting for each other but that could change at any time.

Beside the seeding attempt, the questions are of dubious topicality. Therefore we are destroying the socks, thus obliterating all the questions together with the poster accounts, without much hesitation.

Strictly speaking, the tag does not meet the criteria for burnination, but since we are periodically destroying the socks anyway, there is little to lose here.

**tl;dr**

We would like to burninate the [tdengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tdengine) tag as a moderation measure against seeding and sockpuppetry at a scale that outpaces our moderation capability.

We hope by burninating the tag to render the socks unable to post questions. They would also be unable to recreate the tag due to low rep. If the tag got recreated by higher rep users, we would have someone to go question.

The burnination would be carried out by the Community Managers.

We are posting in Meta to solicit community feedback, in case there are valid reasons for not burninating the tag.

Comment: Certainly a glance over each of questions on the first page seems to support your argument.

Comment: "*We hope by burninating the tag to render the socks unable to post questions*" - what if this fails? Will you restore the tag, both for making the bot questions easier to find and for properly tagging the (few) legit questions where it would be on-topic?

Comment: @Bergi we haven't discussed this aspect, however I think I'd advocate for creating a more specific tag instead, e.g. [tdengine-something] that helps keep questions on topic, instead of a broad catch-all tag.

Comment: The legit questions in there would need to be tagged somehow. There are a few that only have the tdengine tag. Other than that, nuke'm! Bots, bah!

Comment: @blackgreen Not that I really care (I don't know the tag, and it's not a lot of questions), I'm just curious, in particular whether it's even possible to rollback a CM burnination.

Comment: Maybe it would be less work to post on their [GH](https://github.com/taosdata/TDengine/issues) or send an email? If there is a community bot they might turn it off.

Comment: @Bergi I think tags can be (re)created as normal by editing the questions.

Comment: @bad_coder Using that many accounts sounds like it's intended to be bypassing system restriction/spam/something similar.

Comment: Ugh... those low rep accounts posting bazillion low quality questions in that tag look more like spam accounts than actual users.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar if it quacks like a duck...

Comment: Many of the questions I have looked at in that tag so far are categorically off-topic, which makes it a fairly easy process, regardless of whether the tag itself needs burnination. There were 500 questions when I looked; how many questions have been deleted as part of bot/spam destruction that normal users can't see? If it's only one or two dozen, I'm not sure we need to burninate the entire tag.

Comment: @TylerH I'm unable to precisely count them. There's about as many deleted questions as visible ones. Of the deleted questions, the majority has been deleted by Community bot or moderators. I'll guess that around 50 currently deleted posts might have been legit questions, which leaves us with ~450 already deleted inauthentic posts.

Comment: @blackgreen Good info, thanks. That significantly moves the needle on whether the tag itself is worth salvaging.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I figured I'd reach out to TDEngine on their [discord](https://discord.com/invite/VZdSuUg4pS). [I asked them](https://discord.com/channels/953423745601654824/953423745601654827/1211630712764239872) if they're aware of the bots, and if they are, if they could disable them, in order to allow for legit use of the tag:

> Hey there,
> Quick Question: Is TDEngine aware there are bots that repost TDEngine questions to Stack Overflow?
> These bots are getting banned, and the questions are deleted, but they keep coming back...
>
> That kind of automated posting is not allowed there. They're considering blacklisting the [tdengine] tag because of it:
> [Extraordinary burnination: turn off the [tdengine]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429255/extraordinary-burnination-turn-off-the-tdengine)
>
> I'd suggest disabling the bots, so actual users can still use the tag.

A TDEngine moderator & team member [responded](https://discord.com/channels/953423745601654824/953423745601654827/1211695221688107020):

> @Cerbrus thanks for alerting us. I am not aware of any bots but I'll make sure someone takes a look. Thanks!

So, hopefully, it's something they can solve on their end. I'll update this when I get more information.

---

**On Feb. 29th, 2024** [Daniel Clow, TDEngine Operation Manager, responded](https://discord.com/channels/953423745601654824/953423745601654827/1212574492879101992):

> @blackgreen Thanks for bringing this to our attention. Upon investigation it was determined that the low quality reposts on the TDengine tag were part of a misguided effort by our Chinese community manager to increase engagement. Apparently this was a strategy that was being used at their previous employer. At this time they have been instructed to stop posting anything on Stack Overflow and indeed it seems there are no new posts for the past day or two. I would like to apologize on behalf of the company for the wasted time and effort that you and the moderation team spent in dealing with this issue.
>
> Having reviewed the criteria for "burnination" as well as some other
> similar requests posted recently, it seems to me that removing the tag
> entirely is likely unnecessary and it may be best to leave it in place
> for legitimate questions related to TDengine that could be on topic
> for the site.
>
> Thanks again for communicating with us and please let us know at your
> convenience if you have any other concerns now or in the future.

It seems indeed that the illegitimate accounts/questions have stopped. Moderators cleaned up the remaining ones. If you come across older accounts that look illegitimate, please flag for moderator attention. Off-topic questions posted by accounts that look legitimate should be moderated at the community level as usual.

Comment: My tolerance on wait for a response is 1 day. I can't make head or tail of the tag though.

Comment: I posted on their Discord to inform them that we can wait for about 1 week. It waited until now, it can wait one more week.

Comment: First of all: inspiring that you did this. And I think the main thing to take away from this answer is that the meta post should probably have had a station in between going crazy and asking if burnination is okay - "Can we do something about this?". Meta needs to be about more than burning tags :/

Comment: Well there's a happy ending.  Nice to see!

Answer (score 13):

This really looks like [inauthentic usage](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct/inauthentic-usage).  It looks like all of the questions on the first few pages at least are from the same 5 or 6 accounts.

I say burn the tag and the bot accounts.

Comment: What about the legitimate questions? Some of them only have that specific tag.

Comment: @Cerbrus As per a comment on the Answer "we haven't discussed this aspect, however I think I'd advocate for creating a more specific tag instead, e.g. [tdengine-something] that helps keep questions on topic, instead of a broad catch-all tag."