Something's fishy in [dolphindb]
Lately I've noticed a slew of low quality, mis-tagged questions all with one thing in common... the dolphindb tag.
They all seem to be posted in batches from a handful of user accounts and rarely concerning that particular time-series database.
The posts to me almost seem automated and very suspicious.
Might be worth a mod / CM looking into more closely.

It has already been flagged internally, but these tags are a lot of work to handle. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429255/extraordinary-burnination-turn-off-the-tdengine and a few other tags that have been posted about on meta with the same pattern.

Thanks @Zoeisonstrike, certainly looks like the same pattern though I'd definitely suspect the accounts to be voting for each other. I mean, who gave this one an upvote?

Looking at the title, I first thought this is burnination or cleanup request.

Another database technology being astroturfed... Oh, look at that, the excerpt is plagiarized, because of course it is...

See also [tag:iotdb] and/or [tag:apache-iotdb]

I have asked the CM team to look into this. This tag has been problematic for the reasons you've noted.

@Machavity looks like they're back at it with a new-ish set of user accounts

For moderator reference, the CM escalation is here.

Instances of inauthentic usage surrounding the dolphindb tag have been addressed — and rather thoroughly so. For the record, this doesn't leave much legitimate content in that tag.
If you find anything else suspicious that you think might have escaped moderation, please raise a flag as usual.
