# Is moderator intervention required for these Nebula Graph questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

Five different questions on *Nebula Graph* (SO tag: [nebula-graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nebula-graph)) asked by five different people in the last hour.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77122582/how-to-insert-lazily-parsed-quoted-properties-in-code-for-nebulagraph-database
- [In NebulaGraph, the 'MATCH' and 'GO' statements cannot be concatenated using the pipeline symbol (|)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77122557/in-nebulagraph-the-match-and-go-statements-cannot-be-concatenated-using-the)
- [Does NebulaGraph lack computation pushdown to the storage layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77122544/does-nebulagraph-lack-computation-pushdown-to-the-storage-layer)
- [NebulaGraph database data insertion and update issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77122532/nebulagraph-database-data-insertion-and-update-issues)
- [NebulaGraph bears a heavy workload and exhibits elevated CPU utilization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77122509/nebulagraph-bears-a-heavy-workload-and-exhibits-elevated-cpu-utilization)

Does this warrant moderator intervention?

To me the questions appear to be AI generated.

It also appears that they were posted by the same person using different SO accounts. Why would somebody create different accounts in order to post different questions?

Comment: Five people asking five questions looks like SO operating as intended. Are these questions low quality? Off-topic? You need to *explain* what's wrong.

Comment: Except the first one, which seems to be missing the question, all the others seem like genuine questions. What's AI generated about them?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica just checking. If you think there's nothing wrong here, then that's fine by me. By the way, is there an alternative way to report suspicious activity on SO?

Comment: Normally I'd say flagging. But you gotta have some reason to make moderators look into this, not a mere hunch. If you can articulate why the questions seem suspicious, mods can look into it. But I don't think we should be asking mods to delve into something if we ourselves cannot elaborate a bit on what is wrong. You've yet to tell us what led you to suspect the things you do.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica OK. Thanks for the explanation. Should I delete this question?

Comment: At least 5 people asked all a question on the same day in a span of ~10 minutes, at least **3** times. Looks a bit suspicious if you ask me. [astroturfing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroturfing) maybe?

Comment: [this account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22292851/gracechaya) asked 5 questions on the same day in a span of 2 hours. 2 questions just a minute apart...

Comment: We've handled some tags with similar patterns before. I have not looked, so can't verify if it's the case here, but the tags we've seen with similar patterns have usually involved employees at the company making the product the tag is for, vote fraud, and extensive sockpuppetry, and the MO usually being spam-like seeding of questions. The questions can often be off-topic as well, which I'm seeing here too. Wouldn't take long for a mod to verify if there's a problem; it's figuring out how deep the rabbit hole goes that takes time. I strongly recommend you flag

Comment: Similarly formatted questions is also a good indicator. Many of the other questions have identical formatting, with a detail bullet list and a short, code-free question. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77122582/6296561) is AI-generated, which has been a thing on some of the later occurrences of tag seeding spam

Comment: I don't have time to dig into it and fully confirm it right now, but from a quick look at our tooling, there is a potential problem with those questions that is worth a moderator looking at.

Comment: @RyanM It looks like they've been at it for weeks too. There are a bunch of questions that are structured very similarly. I suspect sock puppetry and/or spam seeding.

Comment: Very far-fetched, but also the profile pictures and names follow a certain pattern here. You should definitely flag it. It's better to be too careful than to lose out in the end.

Comment: Definite shades of [oceanbase](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418569/oceanbase-tag-is-being-used-for-fake-questions-and-answers/) here.

Comment: I was actually looking pretty hard at this tag in early Jan 2023. Saw quite a few questions that didn't provide a [mre], used images of text, etc. Also, for the record, the linked questions do not look AI-generated to me (except the first. that's definitely AI).

Comment: I agree with you, @Abra: The whole thing just *smells* bad, and I strongly suspect that there are some bad actors involved.

Comment: this isn't the first time this tag pops up in our radars. it looks like it's time for a follow-up

Comment: It's not just a burst of questions today. Over and over again, looking back through the tag of history, there's a **consistent pattern** of multiple questions posted within minutes, separated by days (typically an entire week) with no activity.

Comment: Seriously, there's no way [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1785170#graph) is organic. Compare to some other tags with the same number of questions in SEDE: [`[testing-library]`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1785175#graph), [`[windows-kernel]`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1785176#graph), [`[collatz]`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1785177#graph). (I guess questions tagged `testing-library` are prone to being deleted, even though that's apparently a real library name.)

Comment: I also can't help but notice: the Oceanbase questions seem to have come largely from English-speaking Chinese users, and the [readme on GitHub](https://github.com/oceanbase/oceanbase) includes a Chinese translation. With nebula-graph, when I look up their promotional material, I'm told right up front that major adopters include Tencent, WeChat (originally Weixin, developed by Tencent), NetEase, vivo and Kuaishou - all Chinese companies.

Comment: The last 100 questions in the tag were mainly asked by a group of about 10 accounts (there are a few seemingly legit questions by legit accounts). Most of these accounts have no reputation. The quesionts have a score of 0 and are basically always posted in bursts of at least 2-3 questions within 10 minutes. This _reeks_ of abuse.

Comment: A [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1785162/2167855) on the questions doesnt give a positive light on users who ask in that tag. One user has asked *43* questions (and 19 answers) and has only *3* posts with a score of >=1 (and they are all 1). It appears they also work for Nebula, based on their GitHub profile. If these are all illegitimate then at least there's little to no vote fraud at the moment (appears historically there was). They really should have just 35 rep (they got the 100 assoc bonus from vote fraud; I wish that could be removed too...)

Comment: Why does this astroturfing stuff seem to happen so much with database technologies? I've seen it with Oceanbase, Apache AGE, Antdb, and now this.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance They might be the same group for all you know.

Comment: Looking at the 5 avatars and the 5 dates of account creation certainly makes me suspicious.

Comment: @PasserBy I don't think that's it. They're all different and probably competing companies/technologies. Apache doesn't have much to do with the AliBaba group or Vesoft (at least not from what I've found). I think some companies tell their interns/employees to do this. This is definitely true of Apache AGE and Oceanbase. I managed to find one employee of Vesoft doing it for Nebula Graph as well.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance It's quite possibly class/school-based.

Comment: Why is a Meta question required for this? Custom mod flag with an appropriate description exists for exactly this reason. We don't need a community witch-hunt every time someone has a suspicion of wrongdoing, that's ultimately for mods to investigate and decide.

Comment: @IanKemp I'm not sure I correctly understand what _Custom mod flag_ is, but if I do correctly understand then I believe you are saying that I should flag all of the questions I linked to in my question, here, as _In need of moderator intervention_. Is that correct?

Comment: @Abra Yes, that is exactly correct. The reason I say "custom mod flag" is that all of the other flags in the dialog have their own specific reasons, but `In need of moderator intervention` effectively requires custom text to be inputted by the flagger, to give enough context to the moderators to perform the investigation.

Comment: @Abra In this case I would have flagged one of these questions as `In need of moderator intervention` with a description and a note that the subsequent flags you will be raising are related to this flag. Then I would've flagged the others again as `In need of moderator intervention` and with a description referencing your first flag.

Comment: @Abra To be clear, I'm not saying that raising this on Meta is necessarily *wrong* - I'd much rather you raised this here, than not at all! It's just that when things get raised here, the questions/answers involved tend to get very heavily stomped on by Meta users, which can interferes with actions that moderators would like to take against said content. Basically, if you don't **have** to involve Meta, try not to!

Comment: These situations [sometimes recur](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/425403/208273) after the mods clean it up. It can help to have people on meta aware of the situation to point it out (despite [my own previous advice to just use a flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418569/oceanbase-tag-is-being-used-for-fake-questions-and-answers/425403#comment914019_418569)).  It also sometimes helps figuring out the extent of the problem, though sometimes that really does require mod tools.  Finally, it helps raise awareness of the general pattern, which has now happened in a few unrelated tags.

Comment: @IanKemp that is context-sensitive, not advice to be given globally. I don't think there is any derailment that the meta effect can have in a situation such as this. It won't change which people are responsible for producing the questions. And who knows, maybe it's a good venue for people who have a desperate need to vote to punish to get it out of their system for the day.

Comment: A better™ [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1785162) to give answer and question counts doesn't look any better (not surprising).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That SEDE graph is a bit misleading since there are so many missing days, yet the points are simply joined by lines. An attempt at a better one: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1785912#graph (but I agree that it doesn't look organic)

Comment: It would be nice to have a lower level of flagging for people who aren’t sure or fear retribution if responsible.

Comment: @fuzzyTew Not really necessary for mod flags; nothing happens except what a human moderator determines should happen when a mod flag is raised. If mods think the flag was not warranted, they will decline it, and often include responses explaining why it was declined. This is a good way for new flaggers to learn and improve their flagging.

Comment: BTW, they're at it again.

Comment: Here's another interesting observation: some accounts have DBA SE accounts as well. I think they noticed the problem back in August because they are suspended until August of 2024.

Comment: Isn't it "[NebulaGraph](https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.1.0/1.introduction/1.what-is-nebula-graph/)" (without the space)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This shows strong evidence of inauthentic usage. In my opinion, this tag is in severe need of cleanup at a minimum. Many of the questions are of dubious quality even if they were asked in good faith (which they clearly weren't). There are many questions in this tag that deserve to be closed and downvoted.

Comment: And the good news is a huge chunk of them are just not about programming, so it's easy to pick a good close reason.